# Weird profiling result on keras models: the more complex the faster

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, profiling, fft

So I am currently trying to figure out which deep learning framework is best to handle fourier transforms. So far I was using `keras` with a `tensorflow` backend, but I noticed the fft was kinda slow (cf [this issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6541#issuecomment-524371619)).

So recently I tried to compare the speed directly with `pytorch`. Since I want to do more than simply do a fourier transform, I tried adding some operations to do a more comprehensive benchmark, and I noticed that for `keras`, adding operations was decreasing the compute time.

Here is the minimal working example (basically doing an inverse fourier transform in 2D, finished by taking the module of the image, and in between potentially "decomplexification" and "recomplexification"):

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.signal import ifft2d
import time

def concatenate_real_imag(x):
    x_real = Lambda(tf.math.real)(x)
    x_imag = Lambda(tf.math.imag)(x)
    return concatenate([x_real, x_imag])

def to_complex(x):
    return tf.complex(x[0], x[1])

def complex_from_half(x, n, output_shape):
    return Lambda(lambda x: to_complex([x[..., :n], x[..., n:]]), output_shape=output_shape)(x)

def weird_model(conc_then_com=False):
    input_size = (320, None, 1)
    kspace_input = Input(input_size, dtype='complex64', name='kspace_input')
    inv_kspace = Lambda(ifft2d, output_shape=input_size)(kspace_input)
    if conc_then_com:
        inv_kspace = concatenate_real_imag(kspace_input)
        inv_kspace = complex_from_half(inv_kspace, 1, input_size)
    abs_inv_kspace = Lambda(tf.math.abs)(inv_kspace)
    model = Model(inputs=kspace_input, outputs=abs_inv_kspace)
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='mse',
    )
    return model

# fake data
data_x = np.random.rand(35, 320, 320, 1) + 1j * np.random.rand(35, 320, 320, 1)
data_y = np.random.rand(35, 320, 320, 1)

start = time.time()
r = weird_model(conc_then_com=True).predict_on_batch(data_x)
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print(f'For the prediction with the complex model it took {duration}')

start = time.time()
r = weird_model(conc_then_com=False).predict_on_batch(data_x)
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print(f'For the prediction with the simple model it took {duration}')

start = time.time()
weird_model(conc_then_com=True).fit(
    x=data_x,
    y=data_y,
    batch_size=35,
    epochs=1,
    verbose=2,
    shuffle=False,
)
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print(f'For the fitting with the complex model it took {duration}')

start = time.time()
weird_model(conc_then_com=False).fit(
    x=data_x,
    y=data_y,
    batch_size=35,
    epochs=1,
    verbose=2,
    shuffle=False,
)
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print(f'For the fitting with the simple model it took {duration}')
```

Which gives the following times (more or less):

```
For the prediction with the complex model it took 0.24
For the prediction with the simple model it took 3.98
For the fitting with the complex model it took 0.28
For the fitting with the simple model it took 4.01
```

I have no idea of what's going on.

Comment: By the way, if some people are interested to know why the fft is so slow in tensorflow, there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6541) closed (but really open) addressing the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was just a typo:
`inv_kspace = concatenate_real_imag(kspace_input)` should be `inv_kspace = concatenate_real_imag(inv_kspace)`